# local storage not working chrome and firefox but it is working in cognito window and private window

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to display a modal when a user visits my page for the first time. If the user visits another page, and then hits the back button, the modal should not show again.

My code works in Incognito (Chrome) and Private Browsing (Firefox), but it does not work in the normal browsing mode in either browser.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyword="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if (isshow== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);

        // Show popup here
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Is it showing the modal when it shouldn't, or not showing it when it should?

Comment: My modal should open in all browsers like chrome and mozila

Comment: But it is working only in incognito window and private window. how to resolve this

Comment: Go into Developer Tools and delete the variable from Local Storage, so you can get back to the state of first going to the page.

Comment: It will only show the first time you go to the page, never again, because of local storage.

Comment: Tell me the procedure, how to go the developer tools,from there what i have to delete

Comment: Press F12 to open Developer Tools.

Comment: This should be basic knowledge to a Javascript developer.

Comment: you are telling console ?

Comment: Yes, Developer Tools is another name for the Web Console.

Comment: From there what i have to delete?

Comment: In Chrome you go to Application, then expand Local Storage, select the URL, click on `isshow` and then press the `X` button to delete it.

Comment: it is working .but I think not suitable for me, because i need like user first tIme means model should open, then he want second time also same url should not open, but he will close the browser the he will open the same page , that time it should show modal,

Comment: Use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. `localStorage` is permanent, `sessionStorage` is only for the current browser session.

Comment: I tried that also but that also not working properly,how means if running index.php means we have to show that modal(first time only),suppose in next tab i am running same url means should not display modal, but when ever using sessionStorage , i am not getting my exact answer

Comment: Each tab is a separate session.

Comment: You could use local storage with a timeout. Instead of storing the number 1, store the time that the user went to the page. Then when they come back, retrieve the value, and get the difference from the current time. If it's more than a certain amount, display the popup.

Comment: Yes,I am using session storege i cann't get my exact requirement, how can do this?

Comment: can you please update your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timeout instead of just checking if the local storage exists.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow') || 0;
    var timeout = 86400000; // 1 day in milliseconds
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - isshow > timeout) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
    }
    localStorage.setItem('isshow', now); // Save the last time we went to the page
});
```

This will show the modal whenever it has been at least 1 day since the last time you went to the page.

Comment: I tried your  code first time modal opened, then i closed the browser running the same url now modal not opening

Comment: You can either use `localStorage`, which is used by all tabs and sessions, or you can use `sessionStorage`, which is separate for every tab and session. There's nothing in between.